# Django rest framework auto-populate filed with user.id/username

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to link 'owner' field of my model to an AbstractUser. I need it to be done automatically, the only think i'm able to do by myself is to allow user logged in to choice between every existing user with, what's not what i want. I would like to not have a field to manipulate, but a outcome serializer with id or username of User that added the model. I'm trying to find solutions for a few days, I've tried already combine ForeignKey, PrimaryKeys, OneToOneField, HiddenField, get_user, perform_create, but I'm for sure doing something wrong, and i'm almost lost with it. The last thing i tried is to def_perform in views like DRF QuickStart tutorial say, but without results.

I add some code sample to be more understandable:

There is my **AbstractUser** model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
...
```

i added it to AUTH_USER_MODEL = in the settings.
And there is **other model** which i want to link with User:

```
    from django.db import models
from users.models.user import UserProfile


class MyPhoto(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images')
```

**serializer.py**

```
class MyPhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = MyPhoto
        fields = ('pk', 'image', 'owner')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        photo = MyPhoto.objects.create(
            image=validated_data['image']
            )
        photo.save()

        return photo
```

**views.py**

```
class UpdateMyPhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyPhoto.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyPhotoSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

and for now i can't see the owner field results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Return `__str__` funcion from `UserProfile` class as field `username` and keep only `owner` instead of `owner.username`

Comment: I'm getting Exception Value: 
<User: API> is not JSON serializable right now.